# Why am I getting 403s when trying to access an aurora serverless database from a lambda but not from the query editor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I've spun up an aurora serverless posgres-compatible database and I'm trying to connect to it from a lambda function, but I am getting `AccessDenied` errors:

> AccessDeniedException:
> Status code: 403, request id: 2b19fa38-af7d-4f4a-aaa5-7d068e92c901

Details:

- I can connect to and query the database manually via the query editor if I use the same secret-arn and database name that the lambda is trying to use. I've triple-checked that the arns are correct
- My lambdas are not in the vpc but are using the data api.  The RDS cluster is in the default vpc
- I've temporarily given my lambdas administrator access so that I know it's not a policy-based issue on the lambda side of things
- Cloudwatch does not contain any additional details on the error
- I am able to query the database from the command line of my personal computer (not on the vpc)

Any suggestions? Perhaps there is a way to get better details out of the error?

Comment: Your lambdas are not in VPC and the RDS is in the default VPC. Your RDS is public or not ? I think you need to check the security group. You can add allow all rule (just to test and delete it later)

Comment: Thanks @Franxihidro.  As far as I can tell, with the aurora serverless data api there isn't quite the same concept of "public" as there is with the non-serverless databases, but I do at least have the http api enabled which should make it accessible from anywhere I'm pretty sure.   I took a look at the security group and it had ingress rules set to have a specific source, which I changed to "everywhere," but I am still getting the same 403 error unfortunately

Comment: Can you create an EC2 in the same VPC/Subnet and do some tests with nc, telnet ip/url port (add -v for more information and open the security group)?. Just to make sure that port is opening.

Comment: Gave it a shot--I ssh'ed into an ec2 box on the same vpn, then I tried the commands below--but they both timeout without giving any info :(

telnet database-1.cluster-etc.rds.amazonaws.com 5432

nc -v database-1.cluster-etc.rds.amazonaws.com 5432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!  After trying to connect via the command line and being able to do so successfully, I realized this had to be something non-network related.  Digging into my code a bit I eventually realized there wasn't anything wrong with the connection portions of the code, but rather with the user permissions being used to create the session/service that attempted to access the data.  In hindsight I suppose the explicit `AccessDenied` (instead of a timeout) should have been a clue that I was able to reach the database just not able to do anything with it.

After digging in I discovered these two things are very different:

- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- AmazonRDSDataFullAccess

If you want to use the data api, you have to have the AmazonRDS**Data**FullAccess (or similar) policy.  AmazonRDSFullAccess is not a superset of the AmazonRDSDataFullAccess permissions as one might assume.  (If you look at the json for the AmazonRDSFullAccess policy you'll notice the permissions cover `rds:*` while the other policy covers `rds-data:*`, so apparently these are just different permissions spaces entirely)

TLDR:  Use the `AmazonRDSDataFullAccess` policy (or similar) to access the data api.  `AmazonRDSFullAccess` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your lambda in the same VPC as your serverless db. I did a quick test and able to connect to it from an EC2 in the same VPC.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-146:~$ telnet database-11.cluster-ckuv4ugsg77i.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
Trying 172.31.14.180...
Connected to vpce-0403cfe830963dfe9-u0hmgbbx.vpce-svc-0445a873575e0c4b1.ap-northeast-1.vpce.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

This is my security group.
[image]